CosmosDB NoSQL Select Multiple Values
If I have data that looks like :
{"Test": {
 "Id":123
 "Name": "Sam",
 "Age": "27"
 }
}

How do I output "Sam: 27"
I have tried
SELECT VALUE {c.Test.Name: c.Test.Age}
FROM c where c.Test.Id = '123'


Typically you would just return the properties (and values) you need and format output in your code, so you’d change your query to something like:
SELECT c.Test.Name AS Name, c.Test.Age AS Age
FROM c
WHERE c.Test.Id = 123

Which returns something like
[
  {
    “Name” : “Sam”,
    “Age” : “27”
  }
]

However - if you truly want to return custom output, then you could concatenate values into a new output value:
SELECT VALUE {
  customtext: CONCAT(c.Test.Name, “: “, c.Test.Age)
}
FROM c
WHERE c.Test.Id = 123

which returns something like:
[
    {
        "combined": "Sam: 27"
    }
]

And lastly, if you don't even want property names, you can output just the value, like this:
SELECT VALUE CONCAT(c.Test.Name,': ', c.Test.Age) 
FROM c
WHERE c.Test.Id = 123

which returns:
[
    "Sam: 27"
]


Is there a way to preserve the curly braces? So that it outputs {"Sam: 27"}

Just change your call to CONCAT() to add the braces at the start and end of your string, just like I added the ': ' in the middle.
